# I am trying to give path to the variable so that I can scrape the information contained in that path. But, I m getting empty list

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to make web scraper using Python and the basic concept I am using here is,

create empty list --> use 'for loop' to loop through the element on the web page. --> append that info in the empty list --> convert that list to row and column using pandas --> finally to a csv.

the code that I made is

```
import requests 
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
url = "https://www.imdb.com/find?q=top+1000+movies&ref_=nv_sr_sm"
results=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser")
# print(soup.prettify())

#initializing empty lists where the data will go
titles =[]
years = []
times = []
imdb_rating = []
metascores = []
votes = []
us_gross = []
movie_div = soup.find_all('div',class_='lister-list')

#initiating the loop for scraper 
for container in movie_div:
    #tiles 
    name=container.tr.td.a.text
    titles.append(name)
print(titles)
```

the website I want to scrap is 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250'. I need help  to know how can i give correct path to the variable 'name', so that i can extract the name of the movie given in name_of_movei, in the HTML script of the page. Because each time I am getting output as empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will parse `name`, `year`, `rating` from the table and creates a dataframe from it:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select(".lister-list > tr"):
    name = row.select_one(".titleColumn a").text.strip()
    year = row.select_one(".titleColumn .secondaryInfo").text.strip()
    rating = row.select_one(".imdbRating").text.strip()
    # ...other variables

    all_data.append([name, year, rating])


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Name", "Year", "Rating"])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Name | Year | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Shawshank Redemption | (1994) | 9.2 |
| The Godfather | (1972) | 9.2 |
| The Dark Knight | (2008) | 9 |
| The Godfather: Part II | (1974) | 9 |
| 12 Angry Men | (1957) | 8.9 |

Comment: Support the approach with list of dicts - Issue may be to get it in US `"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"`

Comment: @HedgeHog I've added `Accept-Language` header to obtain the results in english. Thanks for suggestion :)

Comment: I have a follow - up question, @AndrejKesely... I have data in the <span>_data_</span>... how to get that data? as in the imdb the data is given in <a>_data_</a> ... further, hierarchy, please, mention in comment the thought process you did, for selecting the top div class. Suppose, I have multiple div classes, and my desired data is in a <li>_data</li>, how would I approach it?

Comment: @HedgeHog what to do when the website have token and token changes every time i reload the page, there